# Insert multiple rows with multiple fields with prisma raw query

Tags: prisma

I couldn't find any examples showing how to do this with integers and my options didn't work out(

My table contains 2 columns with integers and I need to add multiple rows to it using prisma raw queries.

If I add just 1 row and use an array of numbers with Prisma.join() - it works fine:

```js
const testArr = [1,3]
return await this.prisma.$executeRaw`
    INSERT INTO public."_CategoryToItem" ("B", "A")
    VALUES (${Prisma.join(testArr)})
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
;`
```

But when using a template string to add multiple rows at once I'm getting the syntax error:

```js
// Exception:
INSERT INTO public."_CategoryToItem" ("B", "A")
    VALUES $1
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  ; ["(1,2),(2,2)"]
Duration: 0ms
[Nest] 1226  - 10/08/2022, 11:41:45 AM   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] 
Invalid `prisma.$executeRaw()` invocation:
    
Raw query failed. Code: `42601`. Message: `db error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"`
```

I was trying this:

```js
const testArr = ['(1,2)', '(2,2)']
return await this.prisma.$executeRaw`
    INSERT INTO public."_CategoryToItem" ("B", "A")
    VALUES (${Prisma.join(testArr)})
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
;`
```

and this:

```js
const testArr = ['(1,2)', '(2,2)']
await this.prisma.$executeRaw`
    INSERT INTO public."_CategoryToItem" ("B", "A")
    VALUES ${testArr.join(',')}
    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
;`
```

It looks like prisma is adding string parentheses around inserted values (but I'm not sure as logs are not very descriptive but it looks like the issue).

Please advise the workaround.

**Note**: I'm using raw query because of working with unsupported type in other related queries so I need the help with the raw query.

Comment: Also I've checked that it works with the executeRawUnsafe but I think it's not a good option due to possible SQL injections: ```return await this.prisma.$executeRawUnsafe(
      `INSERT INTO public."_CategoryToItem" ("B", "A")
      VALUES ${testArr.join(',')}
      ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING
  ;`)```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to avoid unsafe raw queries, you cannot take parts of the SQL expression like `'(1,2)'` as input. That prevents prisma from avoiding SQL injections.

So, you have to have your data in a form like this instead:

```js
const testArr = [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 2],
  ];
```

Assuming a sample schema:

```
model Foo {
  id String @id @default(dbgenerated("gen_random_uuid()")) @db.Uuid
  a  Int
  b  Int
}
```

you can then execute your raw query like this:

```js
await prisma.$executeRaw`
  INSERT INTO "Foo" ("b", "a")
  VALUES ${Prisma.join(
    testArr.map((row) => Prisma.sql`(${Prisma.join(row)})`)
  )}
  ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;`;
```

As you can see, you have to use `Prisma.join` and `Prisma.sql` to build your query. You cannot work with raw strings.

Comment: You helped me out so much.  I tried to mess with the syntax of making this happen for far too long before I found this answer.  Thx!

Comment: Thanks! This answer helped but I have another problem. I'm using this approach to bulk insert records in 50k batches. The problem is this code exceeds the Postgres max bind variables of 32767 in a prepared statement. I can't find it anywhere but is there are way to compile this SQL into its full statement and execute it directly against the db? This way I can benefit from the Prisma safe query and escaping etc, and still do the bug insert.